# Module parse failed: need an appropriate loader to handle this file type using webpack for tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, webpack, tailwind-css, webpack-5, micro-frontend

I am getting the following error inside my webpack configuration:-

```
ERROR in ./style.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@ ./src/bootstrap.js 5:0-22
@ container entry ./MFEApp1[0]
```

I have 3 webpack configurations webpack.common.js, webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js I am trying to configure this for a micro frontend application.
Please find the configuration files below:-

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/InevitableAnup/ed40cb632aa23524611e4debb1aa76fb)